# Open multiple images

Tags: image, powershell

I would like to know how to open multiple images (let's say 2 images for now, using the default Windows Photo Viewer) from a Powershell script.

I've already searched for this and didn't find anything. If this question is already answered on stackoverflow, please inform me.

Comment: is your question answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Invoke-Item](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113345) cmdlet (alias `ii`) to open a item with its default application. So lets say you have to images:

```
$images = @('c:\image1.jpg', 'c:\image2.jpg')
```

you can open them using

```
ii $images
```

If you want for example to retrieve and open all images for a specific folder, you can use the [Get-ChildItem](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113308) cmdlet (alias `gci`), filter for your desired extension and open the images:

```
gci -Path 'your_path' -Filter '*.jpg' | ii
```